# Android Apache - Upload and track progress

Tags: android

I am trying to upload an image using https + post, and track its progress.

```
            StringEntity strEntity = null;
            int totalSize = 0;

            try 
            {
                strEntity = new StringEntity(jsonBody.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
                strEntity.setContentEncoding(HTTP.UTF_8);
                strEntity.setContentType("application/json");
                totalSize = jsonBody.toString().getBytes().length;
            } 
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ProgressHttpEntityWrapper httpEntity = new ProgressHttpEntityWrapper(strEntity, progressCallback, totalSize);
            httpPost.setEntity(httpEntity);
```

I found Here is my class extends HttpEntityWrapper

```
public class ProgressHttpEntityWrapper extends HttpEntityWrapper 
{
    private final ProgressCallback progressCallback;
    private final long fileSize;

    public ProgressHttpEntityWrapper(final HttpEntity entity, final ProgressCallback progressCallback, int fileSize) 
    {
        super(entity);
        this.progressCallback = progressCallback;
        this.fileSize = fileSize;

        Log.e("AsyncUploadData", "Constructor");
    } 

    @Override
    public void writeTo(final OutputStream out) throws IOException 
    {
        Log.e("AsyncUploadData", "writeTo: " +getContentLength());

        super.writeTo(out instanceof ProgressFilterOutputStream ? out
                : new ProgressFilterOutputStream(out, this.progressCallback, this.fileSize));
    }
    .....
}
```

However, I found my "writeTo" method is always being called twice.
I couldn't figure out why!! Please help!

Is it possible to have something to do with my server?
Thanks for any help!!

Comment: You can try http://delimitry.blogspot.in/2011/08/android-upload-progress.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `writeTo()` method is calling `this.wrappedEntity.writeTo()` which I think is redundant.

I used something like this one time:

```
@Override
public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {
    super.writeTo(new CountingOutputStream(outstream, this.listener));
}

public static interface ProgressListener {
    void transferred(long num);
}

public static class CountingOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {

    private final ProgressListener listener;
    private long transferred;

    public CountingOutputStream(final OutputStream out, final ProgressListener listener) {
        super(out);
        this.listener = listener;
        this.transferred = 0;
    }

    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        out.write(b, off, len);
        this.transferred += len;
        this.listener.transferred(this.transferred);
    }

    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        out.write(b);
        this.transferred++;
        this.listener.transferred(this.transferred);
    }
}
```

All credits goes to: http://toolongdidntread.com/android/android-multipart-post-with-progress-bar/

Comment: I changed to "super.writeTo(...)", but it is still called twice :( ...Any suggestion?